# display div when radio button click

Tags: javascript, html

i have a radio button that generated based on database.. 
these are 2 different value of radio button..

```
<div class="form input">
    <?php 
        $so = mysql_query("select code from strength where year = $year"); 
        while($sso = mysql_fetch_array($so))
        {
    ?>
    <span>
        <input name="radio" class="radio" type="radio" value="<?php echo $sso['code']; ?>">
        <label class="choice"><?php echo $sso['code']; ?></label>
    </span>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="form_input">
    <?php 
        $soo = mysql_query("select code from opportunity where year = $year");
        while($sooo = mysql_fetch_array($soo))
        {
        ?>
    <span>
        <input name="radio1" class="radio" type="radio" value="<?php echo $sooo['code']; ?>">
        <label class="choice"><?php echo $sooo['code']; ?></label>
    </span>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

if the `radio` name button is clicked, it will show the 1st div , and if the `radio1` name is clicked, it will the 2nd div,,

how can i do that?

this is my script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var show = document.getElementById('show');
    var show1 = document.getElementById('show1');

    function show()
    {
        show.style.display = 'block';
        show1.style.display = 'block';
    }

    var radio = document.getElementByName('radio');
    var radio1 = document.getElementByName('radio1');

    radio.addEventListener('change',show,false);
    radio1.addEventListener('change',show,false);
</script>
```

apparently , this code doesnt do the task..

this is my full code..

http://pastebin.com/3S8049Xr

this is the div that i want to show..

```
<div id="show" class="form_grid_12" style="display:none;">
    <label class="field_title"></label>
     <div class="form_input">
      A
     </div>
</div>
<div id="show1" class="form_grid_12" style="display:none;">
    <label class="field_title"></label>
    <div class="form_input">
     B
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName instead of document.getElementByName

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code ( jQuery )

```
jQuery('.radio').change(function(){

     if( jQuery('[name="radio"]').is(':checked') ){
        jQuery('#show').show();
     }
     if( jQuery('[name="radio1"]').is(':checked') ){
       jQuery('#show1').show();
     }

});
```

Comment: i want to show both div,, if both radio and radio1 are checked,, then display div and div1 ,,

Comment: @haruya I have updated the code. plz check if it works for you.

Comment: yes,, it work in the fiddle, but when i test on my code, the div is shown before i even check it,,

Comment: Have you initially hidden the div ? for eg. #show, #show1{ display:none; } Initially both the divs should be hidden.

Comment: i've updated my question.. in the bottom of it, that is the `div` i want to show.. if only check one button, it show div 1 and if both check, then display both div..

Comment: you mean on radio click, show should be visible and on radio1 click, show1 should be visible. thats it ?

Comment: yes,, when radio button click, it will display div and when the radio1 button click, it will display div1..

Answer (score 0):

Hope following code will be useful for you...

```
function showhide(obj)
{
    if(obj!=undefined && obj.id=='radio1')
document.getElementById('show1').style.display='block';
    else
        document.getElementById('show1').style.display='none';
}
```

And the html will be

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" onchange='showhide(this);' name="test">Click Me1</input>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" onchange='showhide(this);' name="test" >Click Me2</input>
```

Comment: Will you please paste the entire page here... or tell me what is the issue raised by implementing above code...